# Erro ao consumir serviço em REST. O atributo existe

Tags: java, api, rest

Alguém sabe o motivo do erro abaixo, ao tentar acessar consumir um webservice?
Estava funcionando normal, e começou a apresentar este erro. Já fiz Refresh nas classes, não houve alteração. Ele "reclama" de um atributo, que já existe no response...

```
Context Path:/financeiro-api
Servlet Path:/api
Path Info:/depositos/
Query String:null
```

> **Stack Trace**
>
> ```
> org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: elemento inesperado (uri:"http://www.site.com.br/", local:**"codigoRetorno"**). Os elementos esperados são <{}linkImpressaoBoleto>,<{}msgUsuario>,<{}linhaDigitavelBoleto>,<{}idDeposito>,<{}msgTecnica>,**<{}codigoRetorno>** 
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76)
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212)
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:168)
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:411)
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:202)
> org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
> org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
> org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
> io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
> io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
> io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175)
> io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
> io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:792)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

Comment: Sem o código da requisição não tem como saber qual elemento errado foi enviado para o REST. Leia isso antes de editar a resposta: [***Central de ajuda > Perguntando > Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável***](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)